# Disabling PDF toolbar in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

How to disable PDF toolbar using JavaScript when using

```
 window.open(fi,fnam,items)
```

I used `toolbar='no'` but it disables only Explorer toolbar. What do I need to do  if I want to disable PDF toolbar which is inside Explorer?

Comment: I don't think you can, as this is provided by a plugin and not the browser.

Answer (score 1):

That is part of the Acrobat plugin, and I'm reasonably sure that it isn't possible to manipulate it with JavaScript from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar can be disabled when creating the document. You can also add a Javascript action to the PDF which toggles the toolbar setting. This Javascript runs inside the PDF plugin. It is not exposed to the browser.

Comment: Could you describe how to disable toolbar or insert javascript into a PDF file?