# Disable PDF toolbar in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, toolbar

I am a naive PDF programmer. I want to disable toolbar in PDF generated through JavaScript through

```
window.open(url+"&responsetype=pdf","mytitle");
```

Someone had a similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488048/disable-toolbar-in-javascript). Ambiguous on whether it can be done. Please help.

Comment: How is this question different from [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488048/disable-toolbar-in-javascript) you're referring to?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - Yes they are not different, but wondering if someone who knows stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this will only work if the user has installed Adobe PDF viewer. Experience with other PDF viewers may possibly differ.

Have a look at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf.

The parameter you are interested in, is "toolbar".